# Can I supply a voltage at a specific current? I doubt it

Tags: voltage, led, current, dc

I recently bought a 100W LED module that recommended 24V 5A to operate. However when I power it up using DC power supply that could supply 30V and 5A max, only the fan (for cooling) is functioning, the LED is not light up. And the current being withdrawn by the module is only 0.X A. I contacted the seller, and I get a reply saying that I should supply the module with **24V AT 5A**. The thing is, there's no current demand from the module itself, how I am suppose to supply it? Thus I came to conclusion that the module is defect. Am I right in this case? Or you can actually supply 24V at 5A with some adapter? But I really doubt it.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: If the LED requires 5 Amps at 24 Volts, it should draw that current when supplied with 24 volts.  Are there separate power connections for the fan and the LED?  Have you connected the power with the proper polarity (It's possible (but unlikely) that the fan would work with either polarity, but the LED almost certainly won't.)

Comment: That's exactly what I thought too! Nope, it's just one input for the module to operates. I did connect it in correct polarity. Is it safe to say that the LED is defected?

Comment: Your ideas about current and voltage are correct. But hold on for a moment! Did you confirm that the light is receiving 24V? Also, is there any other input, maybe a dimming input, that you have to drive with a square wave, or maybe just tie it high or low for the light to work?

Comment: The seller could be right. It really depends on the design of the module. The manufacturers datasheet would help. The reason is some electronics implement an overvoltage system. It may be detecting 30 Volts as too high and refusing to turn on to protect itself. For example, most modern cell phones will do this; if your charger voltage is too high it will refuse to charge and perhaps warn you that your charger is faulty.

Comment: No, it would be wrong to say that the "LED is defected". It probably was not defected, but now it likely is, after you put 30V on it. Did you notice a bright blink when you connected it first time?

Comment: Sorry guys, I think I didn't say it in correct way, it was an adjustable DC power supply, which means I could control the voltage, in this case, I used 24V to power up the module, and I did not exceed 28V by any means to prevent it from fry up (28V is the maximum recommended voltage).

Comment: Just to check - you have connected the DC supply the right way round?  LEDs only work one way.  If so, I would suspect that the LED module is faulty.

Comment: If the module requires 24 volts at 5 Amps, I suspect that it includes a current-limiting circuit that may include dimming or colour control.  Does it have any connections other than the power leads?  If you can provide a link to a datasheet or to the vendor's page, someone may be able to offer further information.

Answer (score 1):

If the LED module needs 24V 5A, it likely needs 5A **constant current**, and the resulting voltage could vary, up to 24V in worst case, and likely quite less in reality.

If you have only a 30V DC power supply with no CC (Constant Current) limit mode, an "adapter" could be as simple as a resistor.

You would need to drop 6V (30V - 24V), and to have the 5A current, you would need about 1.2 Ohm resistor. It must be a sizable wirewound resistor capable to dissipate 30 W, a big one. It will be good for a quick experiment, but for real work you would need a dedicated "LED Driver", which is a AC-DC CC-CV power supply with reduced quality.